# Show that $\sin(x^2)$ is integrable around $\infty$.

Tags: integration

I have to show that $f(x)=\sin(x^2)$ is integrable on $[1, \infty[$. This is French terminology, so "intégrable" specifically means that the integral of $|f|$ exists.

The only method I know is to compare it to functions of the form $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$, but it's not eventually smaller or larger than any of these. I can't imagine how it could be asymptotically equivalent to anything useful either, seeing as it oscillates like crazy.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure it's absolute value is integrable, but maybe you can make an argument on the width of the base of your peaks, which have all height $1$. You can also make a change of variables $u=x^2$ to get $$\dfrac 1 2 \int_1^\infty |\sin u|\frac{du}{\sqrt u}$$

Comment: With that last approach you can compare to $\dfrac 1 4 \dfrac{1}{\sqrt u}$ in a rather tricky way. This last function cuts the lumps of your function pretty halfway, then you can argue that the top curved triangle can be used to fill up (with a little extra area left) the "hollow" pointy triangle below. But $$\int_1^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u}$$ diverges, so your integral diverges too.

Comment: This question is a hit.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff: the Lebesgue integral does not converge since the integral of the absolute value diverges. However, the Riemann integral for $[0,\infty)$ is defined as the limit as the upper bound tends to infinity.

Comment: @robjohn I know that Rob! =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean that
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N\sin(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
exists, then change variables $x\mapsto\sqrt{x}$ and integrate by parts:
$$
\begin{align}
&\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_0^N\sin(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\sin(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
+\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac12\int_1^{N^2}\frac{\sin(x)}{x^{1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^1\sin(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
+\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac12\left[\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1/2}}\right]_1^{N^2}
+\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac14\int_1^{N^2}\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{3/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
\end{align}
$$
Now each piece has a limit as $N\to\infty$ since
$$
\int_0^1\sin(x^2)\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
is constant
$$
\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac12\left[\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{1/2}}\right]_1^{N^2}=\frac{\cos(1)-1}2
$$
and
$$
\left|\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{3/2}}\right|\le\frac2{x^{3/2}}
$$
which is integrable over $[1,\infty]$ since $\frac32\gt1$.

Comment: Why $1-\cos(x)$ rather than just $\cos(x)$?

Comment: @JackM Because it works. =)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Wouldn't $-\cos(x)$?

Comment: @JackM Nope, since it is unbounded $x\to 0$ when divided by $x^\alpha$.

Comment: @JackM: because I was going to use the same integration by parts over all of $[0,\infty)$, because $\frac{1-\cos(x)}{x^{3/2}}$ vanishes at $0$ and at $\infty$. However, if that was not obvious to anyone, the explanation would be more confusing that simply breaking the domain into $[0,1)$ and $[1,\infty)$. I changed the domain, but left the integration by parts. After changing the domain, $-\cos(x)$ would have worked, too.

Answer (score 2):

Your function is *not* Lebesgue integrable. As I commented, the absolute value is not integrable. By $u=x^2$ we get $$\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin u|}{2\sqrt u}du$$

Now, consider $f(u)=\frac{1}{4\sqrt u}$. Our integrand is red, this last function is blue. We know that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{du}{\sqrt u}$$ diverges. From the graph, we can see that $$\int_1^\infty \frac{|\sin u|}{2\sqrt u}du> \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{4\sqrt u}du$$ by comparing the size of the red and green triangles. Thus this integral diverges.

(I guess one can make this rigorous, but I think the argument is clear and convincing.)

[image]

**ADD** The  intersection with the $x$-axis are the points $x=\pi k$, i.e. the zeroes of $\sin x$. Solving for the extrema (i.e. using derivatives) gives $\tan x=2x$. These points behave asymtotically like $x=\frac \pi 2+\pi k$. Finally, the intersection of the blue graph with the red graph is given by $|\sin x|=\dfrac 1 4$, thus I don't see it impossible to estimate accurately the areas of the triangles in question.

Comment: @TBrendle What do you mean?

Comment: How can you compare the sizes of the triangles? For a start they're not really triangles as one of their sides is a hyperbola, and secondly their heights and widths don't seem trivial to calculate at all.

Comment: @JackM I really do mean to use triangles, not the curved ones. The green one is still smaller than the curved one over the blue line, yet larger than the red ones, so evidently the size of the curved triangle will be larger than the red ones. And yes, I don't think calculation is trivial, but I thought it was worth sketching why the integral of the absolute value diverged.

Comment: (Actually, finding the coordinates of the triangle's vertices is not difficult at all).

Comment: @TBrendle I know. If you want I'll add them, but I cannot do so now.

Comment: I said the integral of the absolute value diverges, not that the integral diverges.